# This is/these are (parts of a predicate joined by the conjunction "and")

Tags: singular-vs-plural

> These are a kettle and an inkpot.
>   This is a kettle and (this is) an
>   inkpot.

Which sentence is correct? Or both are correct? (The kettle and the inkpot are not considered as a single entity.)

**Update.** I've just come across some similar sentences in "Essential English" by C.E. Eckersley:

> Is this a man and a boy? (accompanied by a picture of a man walking
>   hand in hand with a boy) Is this a cat and a dog? (a picture of a dog,
>   a cat and a bowl between them)

Why are two items considered as one and not separately?

Comment: Brackets discarded, both are correct but mean different things. The first one does mean the two are a single set, while the second indicates a succession of items—this one is..., this one is....

Comment: I wouldn't go so far as to say they're being considered a single entity.  This = what you see before you.  These = the things you see here.

Comment: If I see the kettle and the inkpot, just two items on the table, which grammatical construction should I use?

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo  Using _**these**_ you unite them grammatically: _These [Laurel and Hardy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laurel_and_Hardy) are hilarious, aren't they?_

Comment: @Mv Log : "these Laurel and Hardy" isn't idiomatic.

Comment: @Yulia: Are you backing us into a corner, forcing us to choose between them, or do you want to know what a native speaker is likely to say?

Comment: @MvLog - _These Laurel and Hardy **episodes** are hilarious, aren't they?_ (Or you can use, say, _routines, skits, films, excerpts, YouTube videos_ etc.). The way your sentence is structured, "Laurel and Hardy" should function as an adjective.

Comment: @Yulia: Please flesh out your scenario.  Have we been moving around the room, looking at objects displayed on various tables?  Have I asked what they are?  Are you pointing them out to me, one at a time or gesturing in the direction of the table? etc etc

Comment: Laurel and Hardy are hilarious.  Laurel and Hardy movies are hilarious. These guys are hilarious.

Comment: @Mv Log: "Laurel and Hardy" is not a "list of items". They're a duo.

Comment: @Mv Log: *These apples, pears, and mushrooms were all picked this morning.*  Nothing wrong with that.

Comment: @ Tᴚoɯɐuo: We entered the room, approached the table and I pointed to the things on it saying... what?

Answer (score 1):

"Is this a man and a boy?" to me sounds incorrect.  All I can guess is that the author was using "and" to mean "with" -- "Is this a man with a boy?" would be correct.

Your first two sentences are correct only if you remove the parentheses.  "This is a kettle and an inkpot" should be "These are a kettle and an inkpot."  (Or "This is a kettle, and this is an inkpot."